# Good Libraries to provide html5 and CSS3 features

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css, cross-browser

HTML5 and CSS3 support among major browsers are not consistent. What are the good jquery or any other libraries that provide html5 features in a cross browser manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) will make HTML5 elements work (and by work, I mean the browser will recognise them and you can apply styles to them) in browsers that do not support them, such as old versions of IE

Another good one is [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/), which adds a bunch of unsupported CSS3 selectors to old IE, although a JS library also needs to be used

Answer (score 2):

For CSS3, I highly recommend [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). There are various mixins that can be used to write cross-browser CSS3 stylesheets with fallbacks.

As for HTML5, it isn't really possible to provide HTML5 level features in ALL browsers even if you use the best libraries out there. However, I can recommend [YUI3](http://yuilibrary.com/). YUI3 is developed and sponsored by Yahoo! and is very robust. It also deals well with HTML5 fallback, for example using the History API where avaliable and degrading to the hash based URL scheme if needed. The new [AppFramework](http://stage.yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/app/) is also very very nice.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.initializr.com/ will get you started. It features the best bits of:

- modernizr (inclding the html5shiv)
- bootstrap (including less, some standard jquery plugins that many ppl use
- good, clear reasonings and links to resources

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/). They provide feature detection for many HTML5 and CSS3 features and have a huge list of polyfills to bring those features to non supporting browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) - http://www.modernizr.com/ - designed for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

For CSS3 look at CSS LESS [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org/) 
For HTML5, a good start is using [Html5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)